# HBase Master cannot be contacted by Region Servers

Tags: hadoop, hbase, distributed

I have a Hadoop cluster made of 3 slaves and 1 master on top of which there is an HBase cluster with 3 RS and 1 master respectively. Additionally there is a Zookeeper ensemble on 3 machines.

The Hadoop cluster is functioning correctly as well as the Zookeeper ensemble. However, the HBase cluster fails to initialize correctly.

I start HBase it by running `./bin/start-hbase.sh`. This **correctly** starts the HBase Master and the Region Servers. The hbase folder in hdfs is set-up correctly.

**jps on master**

```
hduser@master:~/hbase$ jps
5694 HMaster
3934 JobHistoryServer
3786 NameNode
3873 ResourceManager
6025 Jps
```

**jps on slaves**

```
5737 Jps
5499 HRegionServer
3736 DataNode
3820 NodeManager
```

However, the HBase master does not register the Region Servers as it is also apparent from looking at the logs:

**master log**

```
[master:master:60000] master.ServerManager: Waiting for region servers count to settle; currently checked in 0, slept for 1511 ms, expecting minimum of 1, maximum of 2147483647, timeout of 4500 ms, interval of 1500 ms.
```

**slave log**

```
[regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to master=master,60000,1404856451890 with port=60020, startcode=1404856453874
[regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending local=/10.0.2.15:53939 remote=master/192.168.66.60:60000]
```

Here are the configuration details:

**/etc/hosts on master**

```
192.168.66.63   slave-3 # Data Node and Region Server
192.168.66.60   master # Name Node and HBase Master
192.168.66.73   zookeeper-3 # Zookeeper node
192.168.66.71   zookeeper-1 # Zookeeper node
192.168.66.72   zookeeper-2 # Zookeeper node
192.168.66.62   slave-2 # Data Node and Region Server
192.168.66.61   slave-1 # Data Node and Region Server
```

**/etc/hosts on slave-1**

```
192.168.66.60   master
192.168.66.73   zookeeper-3
192.168.66.71   zookeeper-1
192.168.66.72   zookeeper-2
```

**hbase-site.xml on ALL cluster nodes**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/hbase/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://master/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/hbase/local</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
        <value>6010</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>zookeeper-1,zookeeper-2,zookeeper-3,</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**regionservers file on master and slaves**

```
slave-3
slave-1
slave-2
```

**hbase-env.sh on master and slaves**

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::"
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

What am I doing wrong so that the nodes cannot talk to each other? I am using Hadoop 2.4.0 and Hbase 0.98.3 along with Zookeeper 3.4.6 on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my mystery was solved by Ian Brooks on the [HBase mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201407.mbox/%3C3884310.mMQxIQ9sn0%40localhost.localdomain%3E)

Essentially I needed to manually specify the slaves in the `/etc/hosts` of the slaves ( I suspect that I only needed to add the slave itself) so that I end up with something like:

**/etc/hosts on all slaves(RS)**

```
192.168.66.60   master
192.168.66.73   zookeeper-3
192.168.66.71   zookeeper-1
192.168.66.72   zookeeper-2
192.168.66.61   slave-1
192.168.66.62   slave-2
192.168.66.63   slave-3
```

The reason for this was that there were to eth interfaces running on the slaves and the localhost was addressed on a different IP.